# Lightweight browser with pdf/docx plugin

Tags: xubuntu, pdf, browser

Im running xubuntu on a 'designed for xp' netbook (my friend corrupted system32) and looking for a web browser that will run smoothly [2gb ram, intel atom] and open pdf/docx files in the browser, this is all i use the netbook for.  Not sure if this is possible just firefox runs sluggish.

Thanks for help in advance and i understand it might not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am **Ubuntu** User. I get `pdf reader(Evince) for pdf documents` and `Libre office for docx documents` by default. In xubuntu you should also be getting same default programs. I didn't understand why you specifically want to view them with browser when dedicated software for the same purpose is already available with the system.
Edit-
Well if you want to use browser anyway go for chrome. You can install and try [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office-editing-for-docs-s/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj?hl=en) for office documents and [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office-editing-for-docs-s/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj?hl=en) for pdf documents. Additionally you can search more extensions for the same purpose. Anyway you are still downloading documents for view. Though they will not store in your hard disk but downloaded for temporary view only.

Comment: I use it for my uni studies, and generally I'm opening a lot of documents and flicking through so downloading and managing them is just hard work, it's a ease of life thing.

Comment: In my experience, Chrome is painfully slow (if it works at all) on such old hardware with low RAM. Firefox runs significantly faster (though not "fast" by any means)

Comment: You may be right. I suggested it as an alternative to Firefox. In such older hardware optimization is very important.periodical De-fragmentation of Hard disk and cleaning of junk from system will improve the performance.